# How to Select record between a given time range and Item Category

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I have an MS Access database table "tbltransactions" with seperate date and time column. I need to select all data from my table checking three conditions

**1.records that are in a specific category.**

**2.records with custom date range I set.**

**3.records with custom time range I set.**

My table structure is shown below

```
+-------+---------+-------+--------+------------+-------------+------------+
|  id   |  item   | units | Amount | category   |  adddate    |  addtime   |
+-------+---------+-------+--------+------------+-------------+------------+
|  1    |    A    |   1   |  100   |   toys     |  5/23/2016  |  8:05 AM   |
+-------+---------+-------+--------+------------+-------------+------------+
|  2    |    A    |   1   |  100   |   toys     |  5/23/2016  |  8:45 AM   |
+-------+---------+-------+--------+------------+-------------+------------+
|  3    |    B    |   1   |  200   |   book     |  5/23/2016  |  9:05 AM   |
+-------+---------+-------+--------+------------+-------------+------------+
|  4    |    A    |   1   |  100   |    toys    |  5/23/2016  |  9:25 AM   |
+-------+---------+-------+--------+------------+-------------+------------+
|  5    |    A    |   1   |  100   |   toys     | 5/23/2016  |  11:05 AM   |
+-------+---------+-------+--------+------------+-------------+------------+
|  6    |    A    |   1   |  100   |   toys     | 5/23/2016  |  1:10 PM    |
+-------+---------+-------+--------+------------+-------------+------------+
|  7    |    A    |   1   |  100   |   toys     |  5/23/2016  |  3:30 PM   |
+-------+---------+-------+--------+------------+-------------+------------+
|  8    |    A    |   1   |  100   |   toys     |  5/23/2016  |  4:12 PM   |
+-------+---------+-------+--------+------------+-------------+------------+
|  9    |    A    |   1   |  100   |   toys     |  5/23/2016  |  5:47 PM   |
+-------+---------+-------+--------+------------+-------------+------------+
|  10   |    A    |   1   |  100   |   toys     |  5/23/2016  |  6:22 PM   |
+-------+---------+-------+--------+------------+-------------+------------+
|  11   |    B    |   1   |  200   |   book     |  5/24/2016  |  8:15 AM   |
+-------+---------+-------+--------+------------+-------------+------------+
|  12   |    B    |   1   |  200   |   book     |  5/24/2016  |  9:33 AM   |
+-------+---------+-------+--------+------------+-------------+------------+
|  13   |    A    |   1   |  100   |   toys     |  5/24/2016  |  1:03 PM   |
+-------+---------+-------+--------+------------+-------------+------------+
|  14   |    B    |   1   |  200   |   book     |  5/24/2016  |  2:22 PM   |
+-------+---------+-------+--------+------------+-------------+------------+
|  15   |    A    |   1   |  100   |   toys     |  5/24/2016  |  3:10 PM   |
+-------+---------+-------+--------+------------+-------------+------------+
|  16   |    A    |   1   |  100   |   toys     |  5/24/2016  |  4:07 PM   |
+-------+---------+-------+--------+------------+-------------+------------+
|  17   |    A    |   1   |  100   |   toys     |  5/24/2016  |  6:15 PM   |
+-------+---------+-------+--------+------------+-------------+------------+
|  18   |    B    |   1   |  200   |   book     |  5/24/2016  |  6:17 PM   |
+-------+---------+-------+--------+------------+-------------+------------+
|  19   |    A    |   1   |  100   |   toys     |  5/24/2016  |  6:30 PM   |
+-------+---------+-------+--------+------------+-------------+------------+
|  20   |    B    |   1   |  200   |   book     |  5/24/2016  |  6:42 PM   |
+-------+---------+-------+--------+------------+-------------+------------+
```

I can select record based on category and a specific date

```
sql = "SELECT id, item 
         FROM Table1
        WHERE category ='toys' 
          AND DateValue(adddate) = #'5/23/2016'#
```

this returns records  **1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10**

I can also select record based on category and a date range

```
sql = "SELECT id, item 
         FROM Table1
        WHERE category ='toys' 
          AND DateValue(adddate) > #'5/23/2016'# 
          AND DateValue(adddate) <= #'5/24/2016'#
```

this returns records  **1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,13,15,16,17,19**

now I need to get record from **5/23/2016 8:00 AM**  to **5/24/2016 3:00 PM**. How to do this?

Comment: my adddate and addtime are text fields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider concatenating string/date values in the `CDate()` function available in Jet/ACE ODBC as well as the Access.exe UI:

```
sql = "SELECT id, item 
         FROM Table1
        WHERE category ='toys' 
          AND CDate(adddate & ' ' & addtime) > CDate('5/23/2016 8:00 AM')
          AND CDate(adddate & ' ' & addtime) <= CDate('5/24/2016 3:00 PM')
```

Alternatively, use `BETWEEN` operator (which includes end points, so I add a second):

```
sql = "SELECT id, item 
         FROM Table1
        WHERE category ='toys' 
          AND CDate(adddate & ' ' & addtime) 
          BETWEEN CDate('5/23/2016 8:01 AM') AND CDate('5/24/2016 3:00 PM')
```

Answer (score 0):

You may concatenate the `adddate` and `addtime` column and convert to a `datetime` type to use for compare.

Below is an example in MSSQL and other platform should be similar:

```
SELECT id, item 
WHERE category ='toys' AND 
CONVERT(DATETIME, adddate + ' ' + addtime) BETWEEN '5/23/2016 8:00 AM' AND '5/24/2016 3:00 PM'
```

Comment: OP mentions *Access database*. Please update for MS Access SQL dialect.

Answer (score 0):

For `record from 5/23/2016 8:00 AM to 5/24/2016 3:00 PM`, you could seperate the range to `(date = 5/23 and time > 8:00 AM) or (date=5/24 and time < 3:00 PM)`

So you could use this

```
sql = "SELECT id, item WHERE category ='toys' AND  ((DateValue(adddate) = #'5/23/2016'# AND  TimeValue(addtime) >= #'8:00:00 AM'#) OR (DateValue(adddate) = #'5/24/2016'# AND TimeValue(addtime) <= #'3:00:00 PM'#))"
```